# Como faço para usar MySQL Federated?

Tags: mysql, engine

Estou precisando usar a Engine FEDERATED no meu banco de dados MySQL porém por padrão a mesma vem desabilitada, em alguns foruns diz que para habilitar é preciso ir até o arquivo de configuração my.ini e adicionar a linha federated abaixo da [mysqld], fiz tal procedimento mas sem sucesso.

Existe mais algum lugar que posso alterar para habilitar tal função.

Uso MySQL Server 5.6
Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bits.

---

Fiz o procedimento acima porém sem sucesso, tenho o print de como é retornado pra mim no Workbench ao pesquisar usando show engines.

[image: my.ini]

[image: show engines pesquisa]

---

---

Comment: Qual foi o caminho do arquivo alterado?

Comment: você precisa habilitar no my.cnf também

Comment: Otto my.cnf esta em qual caminho?

Comment: Já tentou pesquisar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solucionei o problema de outra forma.

Primeiro pare o serviço do banco de dados por meio do  Startup/Shutdown

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois acesse a opção Options File

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na tela do Options File na aba General temos a segunda opção federated desabilitada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Habilite o check box e informe o valor de ON no campo a frente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso clique em apply e depois apply novamente na nova janela

Volte a função Startup/Shutdown e inicie o servidor novamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E confirme no prompt de comando realizando um show engines tendo que retornar igual a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Segundo [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883149/enable-federated-engine-in-mysql-5-6-windows) o arquivo alterado deve ser o my.ini da pasta:
`C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`, para ativar o engine federated

- Pare o serviço do mysql.
- Abra o my.ini adicione uma nova linha com o conteúdo `federated` logo a baixo da seção `[mysqld]`.
- Inicie o serviço novamente e execute a consulta: `show engines`. O resultado deve ser algo parecido com a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A linha que devo adicionar federated é abaixo do [mysqld], ou no final de todas as instruções que tem abaixo?

Comment: Abaixo de `[mysqld]`

Comment: como segue no print que postei acima?

Comment: Isso mesmo, so veja se é o my.ini do `c:\programdata`

Comment: O arquivo se chama my-default.ini e fica em C:\Arquivos de Programas\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my-default.ini dai fiz o procedimento que passou porém sem sucesso.

Comment: No caminho passado na resposta existe o my.ini?

Comment: Realmente não consegui, fazer a ativação da Engine FEDERATED por meio de alteração do arquivo my.ini. Pode ser algum problema de versão do MySQL que não tenha suporte ao Engine.

Comment: Eu testei aqui com o win8 32bits e mysql 5.6

Comment: @ClaytonQuintiliano, deu certo? qual era o problema?

Comment: A tarefa acima sanou meu problema. Obrigado

Comment: Seguinte fiz a alteração acima porém não surtiu efeito algum, hoje estou testando em um micro com Windows 8.1 só que 32 bits e apresentava o mesmo problema que o Windows 64 bits. Procurando outra função acessei a Options File em manutenção do Workbench e lá possui um campo na Guia General com o nome de Federated sem estar ticado. Ao ticar a opção liberou uma opção para informar um valor, ao acaso informei ON. E ao inicial o servidor novamente habilitou a função FEDERATED. Agora irei testar na máquina de 64 bits.

Comment: @ClaytonQuintiliano, já que funcionou poste esse procedimento como um resposta, eu não conhecia essa maneira de habilitar o `federated engine` pelo workbench.